# Drupal JSON Server and Services Module only returns Invalid Method

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-6

I have been trying to get a stock Drupal site up and running with JSON Server module and Services.  After install I added the two modules and enabled them.  When I use Curl from the command line to call system.connect or anything I only get Invalid Method.

`curl --data method=system.connect http://localhost/services/json`

This is what I am getting back.

```
{ "#error": true, "#data": "Invalid method " }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having the same problem myself a while back. Your problem at the moment is that your post data does not have quotes.

```
curl --data 'method="system.connect"' http://localhost/services/json
```

If you have a look at this: http://drupal.org/node/305799 it should give you loads more info to get you going with services and the json server.

Comment: Thanks that was my issue.  Now I just have to figure out why even though my parameters are optional it is stating "Argument fields not recieved.

Comment: From that error message it sounds as though for some reason there is a parameter called fields which isn't optional for some reason. Have you got '#optional' set to 1 for that method?